# Change Array Name php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach, explode

I want to load a CSV file dynamically into php and store it in an array. I can't get the array name changed to the form I want it to be. The first array should be numbered as normal, the second should contain the header of the CSV file.

This is my current function to solve the problem:

```
static function parseCSV($path){

        $fp = file($path);
        $array = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fp); $i++) {
            $e = explode("," , $fp[$i+1]);
            foreach($e as $data){
                $array[$e[0]][] = $data;
            }
        }
        
        print_r($array);
    }
```

This is the Output:

```
Array
(
    [Louis] => Array
        (
            [0] => Louis 
            [1] => 000               
            [2] => 01.01.2001
            [3] => Canada
        )

    [Hannah] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hannah
            [1] => 001              
            [2] => 02.02.2002             
            [3] => Germany        


        )
)
```

The output I would like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Louis 
            [id] => 000               
            [birthday] => 01.01.2001
            [country] => Canada
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Hannah
            [id] => 001              
            [birthday] => 02.02.2002             
            [country] => Germany        


        )
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10181054/367456

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new row data array with the specific array index:

```
static function parseCSV($path){
        $headers = ['name', 'id', 'birthday', 'country'];
        $fp = file($path);
        $array = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fp); $i++) {
            $rows = explode("," , $fp[$i+1]);
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $associativeArray = array();
                foreach($row as $index=>$value) {
                    $associativeArray[$headers[$index]] = $value;   
        
                }
                array_push($array, $associativeArray);
            }
        }
        
        print_r($array);
    }
```

Comment: ``$array[$i + 1][] = [ 'name' => $e[0], 'id' => $e[1], 'birthday' => $e[2], 'country' => $e[3]`` Also, you don't the inner foreach then.

Comment: This works, but I need to be able to load the data dynamically from the CSV file.

Comment: Are your csv headers always fixed ? Will you always have name, id, birthday and country?

Comment: Yes, they are always the same in this task. But I simplified it a bit for this, I actually have a lot more data.

Comment: You can have a headers array separately and run a loop to set them in. Updated answer.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it didn't work at all.