# How to generate an associate array from text in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, explode

I have been creating arrays from plain text by using comma `,` (or any other special character) with the help of php's `explode()` function like

```
$rawPhoneNumber = "800-555-5555"; 
$phoneChunks = explode("-", $rawPhoneNumber);
echo "Raw Phone Number = $rawPhoneNumber <br />";
echo "First chunk = $phoneChunks[0]<br />";
echo "Second chunk = $phoneChunks[1]<br />";
echo "Third Chunk chunk = $phoneChunks[2]";
```

But How can I create an associative array? Like how can I create an array like

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
```

from a plain text like "Peter=>35,Ben=>37,Joe=>43"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your input format is close enough to PHP native to suggest `eval`:

```
$ages = eval('return array(' . file_get_contents('ages.txt') . ');');
print_r($ages);
```

Example:

```
$ cat ages.txt
Peter=>35,Ben=>37,Joe=>43
$ php example.php
Array
(
    [Peter] => 35
    [Ben] => 37
    [Joe] => 43
)
```

But for security and performance reasons, you're better off using [string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14133780/2908724).

---

If you want to keep data in file, using PHP data structures, I'd suggest using `var_export` and writing to a file you later `include`:

```
$ages = array ('Peter' => 35, 'Ben' => 37 );
file_put_contents('ages.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($ages, true) . ';');

$readback = include('ages.php');
print_r($readback);
```

Example:

```
$ php example.php
Array
(
    [Peter] => 35
    [Ben] => 37
)
$ cat ages.php
<?php return array (
  'Peter' => 35,
  'Ben' => 37,
);
```

Comment: But sanitise the hell out of your input before doing this!

Comment: you say that the other code has more performance than my current input text and our code?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ Just saying that, in general, `eval` and `file_get_contents` are not going to be super efficient.  If you want to store the data in a file, in a PHP like syntax, then you're better off doing something like my edit.

Comment: Any way, I am not using a file and the text is retrieved from mysql db. So what do you suggest? My "php like" text solution or the other solution from the linked qn?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ You're not using a file?  But your OP said *<<from a plain text like "Peter=>35,Ben=>37,Joe=>43">>*... Anyway, if this string is stored in a DB, I'd suggest using a proper ages table.  If not that, then I'd suggest string manipulation.  I've added another answer using `strtok`, which might be more to your liking.

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ http://stackoverflow.com/q/951373/2908724

Comment: This will solve my problem for now. I will be *very very careful*

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there are more elegant ways, but... this should work, too.

```
$str='Peter=>35,Ben=>37,Joe=>43';
$arr=explode(',',$str);
$final=array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
$val=explode('=>',$value);  
$final[$val[0]]=$val[1];    

}

print_r($final);
```

Comment: And this is one of them

Comment: but this will use multiple loops

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, if you worry about performance, maybe there are better ways, not sure(that's why i said that there must be more elegant ways, one of plenty php functions maybe could help, don't know)...

Answer (score 1):

Hell, why not.  A two-line PHP 5.5+ solution using `array_column` and friends:

```
$input  = 'Peter=>35,Joe=>37';

$chunks = array_chunk(preg_split('/(=>|,)/', $input), 2);
$result = array_combine(array_column($chunks, 0), array_column($chunks, 1));

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [Peter] => 35
    [Joe] => 37
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

$rawPhoneNumber = "800-555-5555"; 
$phoneChunks = explode("-", $rawPhoneNumber);

$myarray['Raw Phone Number'] = $rawPhoneNumber;
$myarray['First chunk'] = $phoneChunks[0];
$myarray['Second chunk'] = $phoneChunks[0];
$myarray['Second chunk'] = $phoneChunks[0];
$myarray['Third chunk'] = $phoneChunks[0];

Result:
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarray);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

------------- Think this will work for you -----------------

```
<?php
```

$sample = "Peter=>35,Ben=>37,Joe=>43"; 
$row_chunks = explode(",", $sample);

```
foreach ($row_chunks as $value) 
{
    $row_chunks = explode("=>", $value);
    $myarray[$row_chunks[0]]=$row_chunks[1];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarray);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: whats wrong with my answer ? please explain

Comment: Yours is a manual solution, not automatic. The array may have fewer or larger number of entries. The key name varies. Got it?

Comment: Fine but you didn't mention it in the question. could you please provide a sample output that you need ? your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Looking your condition this will work

```
<?php
$content = 'Peter=>35,Ben=>37,Joe=>43';
$arr = explode(',',implode(',',explode('=>',$content)));
$assoArray = Array();
for($i =0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i +=2)
{
    $assoArray[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i +1];
}
print_r($assoArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32766571/2908724), [`array_walk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14134241/2908724), [`foreach` with an `explode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14133869/2908724), or even `strtok`:

```
$input = 'Peter=>35,Ben=>37,Joe=>43';
$array = array ();

$part = strtok($input, ',');
while (false !== $part) {
    list ($name, $age) = explode('=>', $part);
    $array[$name] = $age;
    $part = strtok(',');
}

print_r($array);
```

There is virtually no end to the convoluted ways you can do this.