# How to explode multidimensional array with key and value

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a string like this:

```
$string = Leader,Brian; Elder,Nina,Maria; Member,Duke,Rai,Mike
```

What I've done:

```
$explode = ("; ", $string);
```

Then it will show like:

```
Array ([0] => Leader,Brian [1] => Elder,Nina,Maria [2] => Member,Duke,Rai,Mike)
```

But I don't like that. I want to make a multidimensional array with key and value, like this:

```
Array ([Leader] => Brian [Elder] => Array ([0] => Nina [1] => Maria) 
       [Member] => Array ([0] => Duke [1] => Rai [2] => Mike))
```

How to show it in table tag html like this?

```
Leader  |  Brian
Elder   |  Nina
        |  Maria
Member  |  Duke
        |  Rai
        |  Mike
```

**NB:** You can change the separator in string if it's difficult with separator like that

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133780/explode-a-string-to-associative-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre `explode` is a good first step.

Next one is to iterate its result and explode it again.
Then (in the same loop) use first element of the second `explode`'s result as key and the rest as value.

```
$string = "Leader,Brian; Elder,Nina,Maria; Member,Duke,Rai,Mike";

$exploded = explode("; ", $string);

foreach($exploded as $element) {
    $arr = explode(',', $element);

    $result[array_shift($arr)] = $arr;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  ["Leader"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Brian"
  }
  ["Elder"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Nina"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Maria"
  }
  ["Member"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Duke"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Rai"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Mike"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show it's in tag table html, please?. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would probably walk the array after splitting the string and split again:

```
$list = explode("; ", $string);
array_walk($list, function(&$element) {
    $names = explode(',', $element);
    // Take the first item off the array type
    $type = array_shift($names);
    // Alter the array in-place to create the sub-array
    $element = [$type => $names]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two "explodes"

```
$string = 'Leader,Brian; Elder,Nina,Maria; Member,Duke,Rai,Mike';
$explode = explode("; ", $string);
foreach($explode as $row){
    $explode2 = explode(",", $row);
    foreach($explode2 as $i=>$p ){

        echo ( $i > 0 )?"\n\t|":"\n";
        echo $p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explode twice - on your two delimiters, for example:

```
<?php
$string = "Leader,Brian; Elder,Nina,Maria; Member,Duke,Rai,Mike";

$result = array();
$parts = explode(";", $string);

foreach ($parts as $part)
{
    $kv = explode(",", $part);
    $result[array_shift($kv)] = $kv;
}

// result:
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Will give you:

```
Array
(
    [Leader] => Brian
    [Elder] => Nina
    [Member] => Duke
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php
$string = 'Leader,Brian; Elder,Nina,Maria; Member,Duke,Rai,Mike';

$explode = array_map(function($v){return explode(',', $v);}, explode(';', $string));

$new_array = [];

foreach($explode as $k=>$v)
{
    $v[0] = trim($v[0]);

    $new_array[$v[0]] = $v;

    unset($new_array[$v[0]][0]);

    $new_array[$v[0]] = array_values($new_array[$v[0]]);
}

print_r($new_array);
```