# PHP - Associative array levels from MySQL row values

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

### The model

I've got a database with multiple categories and values associated with objects, so an element X can have a "city" with value "Sevilla", a "country" with value "Spain", and so on. The database scheme is the following:

```
+------------+-------------+----------+
| element_id | category_id | value_id |
+------------+-------------+----------+
|          1 |           1 |        1 |
|          1 |           2 |        5 |
|          1 |           3 |        2 |
+------------+-------------+----------+
```

These, of course, are linked to other tables where I store the values of that IDs.

### The beginning

The user can choose to see the elements grouped by their categories, in the order the user wants. So, a user may want to see the elements grouped by "country" and, then, by "city". Or maybe by "city", and then by "neighbourhood". And so on.

**The user defines the order of the groups, the user decides "what goes inside what".**

### The result I got after querying database

I've got a result from a query (so, I've already done the query and this would be the information I would get with `fetch_object()`) with the following structure (and example data):

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id |  value    | category_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | Spain     |           1 |
|  1 | Sevilla   |           2 |
|  2 | Portugal  |           1 |
|  2 | Lisboa    |           2 |
|  3 | Spain     |           1 |
|  3 | Barcelona |           2 |
|  4 | Spain     |           1 |
|  4 | Sevilla   |           2 |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

### What I'd like

What I'd like to do is to end up having an associative array in PHP like the following:

```
array(2) {
  ["Portugal"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Lisboa"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
      }
    }
  }
  ["Spain"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Sevilla"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(4)
      }
    }
    ["Barcelona"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, by order of appearance, every element with the same ID as the previous one gets into a new child level of the associative array, and end up having an array of objects of all those elements which have that same path.

Keep in mind that there can be different levels of deep, so maybe (and that is chosen by the user), can be another `value` under "Sevilla", so I cannot have variable for everything that can come, because it depends on the user.

I've been struggling to find out how to do it but I have not been able to. I've found [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133780/explode-a-string-to-associative-array) but, though it's a similar case, nothing comes to my mind regarding how to apply it to get the desired result.

Thank you.

Comment: Edited the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The user decides what goes inside what, because the user can choose to see `country->street` or even `city->country` so he sees the name of the city first and then, inside it, he sees to which countries a city named like that belongs to (can be two cities with same name on diferent countries).

Answer (score 0):

This data structure is ugly. Think about changing your query instead. I wrote this for `$result` array iteration, but it's easy to switch into `fetch_object` while loop (don't know what kind of object you get).

```
$data = [];
$city = $country = $id = null;
foreach ($result as $row) {
    if ($id != $row['id']) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $country = $row['value'];
        isset($data[$country]) or $data[$country] = [];
        continue;
    }

    $city = $row['value'];
    isset($data[$country][$city]) or $data[$country][$city] = [];
    $data[$country][$city][] = ['id' => $id];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my question, because this part may not be clear. The number of rows of each element can change, so maybe a user wants to see only countries, while other can see countries and cities, and other can see countries, cities and streets, for example. So, for the first item, the array can be (if the user chooses to) `$array['Spain']['Sevilla']['Triana'] = array('id' => 1);`. The number of levels can be 1 or more, but that "more" is defined by the user. Thank you!