# Convert string with two delimiters into flat associative array

Tags: php, regex, explode

I'm really have no idea about regex...
So I got stuck... Can anyone give me a solution with explanation of regex itself?

Here is my code:

```
$str = "id:521082299088|name:JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA|mounth:JAN17|amount:170027|admin:2500|billqty:1|metre:R1/900|usage:00010261-00010550|reffno:0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA|charge:170377|balace:1935";
$pregsplit = preg_split("/[\s|]+/",$string2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id:521082299088
    [1] => name:JOHNSON
    [2] => GREIG
    [3] => DENOIA
    [4] => mounth:JAN17
    [5] => amount:170027
    [6] => admin:2500
    [7] => billqty:1
    [8] => metre:R1/900
    [9] => usage:00010261-00010550
    [10] => reffno:0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA
    [11] => charge:170377
    [12] => balance:1935
)
```

I want output like this:

```
Array
(
    "id" => 521082299088
    "name" => "JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA"
    "mount" => "JAN17"
    "amount" => 170027
    "admin" => 2500
    "billqty" => 1
    "metre" => "R1/900"
    "usage" => "00010261-00010550"
    "reffno" => "0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA"
    "charge" => 170377
    "balance" => 1935
)
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** The solution using `preg_match_all` function with specific regex pattern:

```
$str = "id:521082299088|name:JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA|mounth:JAN17|amount:170027|admin:2500|billqty:1|metre:R1/900|usage:00010261-00010550|reffno:0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA|charge:170377|balace:1935";

preg_match_all("/(\w+):([^|]+)/", $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$result = [];
foreach ($matches as $items) {
    $result[$items[1]] = $items[2];
}
// $items[1] contains a "parameter" name captured by the first capturing group (\w+)
// $items[2] contains a "parameter" value captured by the second capturing group ([^|]+)

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 521082299088
    [name] => JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA
    [mounth] => JAN17
    [amount] => 170027
    [admin] => 2500
    [billqty] => 1
    [metre] => R1/900
    [usage] => 00010261-00010550
    [reffno] => 0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA
    [charge] => 170377
    [balace] => 1935
)
```

`(\w+)`   - matches all alphanumeric characters followed by `:`

`([^|]+)` - matches all characters excepting `|` which is delimiter

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

---

**2)** In addition to the first approach - using `array_combine` function(to combine all respective values from two capturing groups):

```
preg_match_all("/(\w+):([^|]+)/", $str, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
// will give the same result
```

---

**3)** The third alternative approach would be using `explode()` function:

```
$result = [];
foreach (explode("|", $str) as $items) {
    $pair = explode(":", $items);
    $result[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me that regex ? for each characters

Comment: @KurniawanNanda, added explanation

Comment: It seems the positive lookahead isn't necessary in your expression.

Comment: @KurniawanNanda I would recommend you to search for online live regex editing tools to practice it. Those would help to understand regexes better. I would really recommend regexr.com for example.

Comment: @Niitaku, ok, removed

Comment: @Kurniawan Nanda you can just use explode() method.If you are new in regular expression.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanksssssssssssssssss I really appreciate that

Comment: If you remove `PREG_SET_ORDER`, you can build the result using `array_combine` without a loop.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, ok, added as an alternative

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to write regular expression.Here is a simple solution using `explode()` method.The `explode()` function breaks a string into an array.

```
<?php
$str = "id:521082299088|name:JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA|mounth:JAN17|amount:170027|admin:2500|billqty:1|metre:R1/900|usage:00010261-00010550|reffno:0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA|charge:170377|balace:1935";

$array = explode('|',$str);
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
 $data = explode(':',$value);
 $final[$data[0]] = $data[1];

}
print_r($final);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 521082299088
    [name] => JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA
    [mounth] => JAN17
    [amount] => 170027
    [admin] => 2500
    [billqty] => 1
    [metre] => R1/900
    [usage] => 00010261-00010550
    [reffno] => 0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA
    [charge] => 170377
    [balace] => 1935
)
```

To learn more about `explode()` read docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

A funny way (only if your string doesn't contain `=` or `&`): translate pipes to ampersands and colons to equal signs, then parse it as an URL query with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$str = "id:521082299088|name:JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA|mounth:JAN17|amount:170027|admin:2500|billqty:1|metre:R1/900|usage:00010261-00010550|reffno:0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA|charge:170377|balace:1935";

parse_str(strtr($str, ':|', '=&'), $result);

print_r($result);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/726105)

Answer (score 0):

This approach would be an alternative.

You can separate string and create an array from it using PHP's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. Then you can separate the `'key:value'` structure using [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) functions.

```
// input string
$str = "id:521082299088|name:JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA|mounth:JAN17|amount:170027|admin:2500|billqty:1|metre:R1/900|usage:00010261-00010550|reffno:0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA|charge:170377|balace:1935";

// make an array out of the string, split elements on each pipe character ('|')
$arr = explode('|', $str);

// create an output array to keep the results
$output = [];

// process the array
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    // get delimiter
    $separatorPos = strpos($item, ':');
    // take the key part (The part before the ':')
    $key = substr($item, 0, $separatorPos);
    // take the value part (The part after the ':')
    $value = substr($item, $separatorPos);
    // push it into the output array
    $output[$key] = $value;
}

// dump the output array
var_export($output);
```

Dump of the output array would be like follwing;

```
[
    'id'      => ':521082299088',
    'name'    => ':JOHNSON GREIG DENOIA',
    'mounth'  => ':JAN17',
    'amount'  => ':170027',
    'admin'   => ':2500',
    'billqty' => ':1',
    'metre'   => ':R1/900',
    'usage'   => ':00010261-00010550',
    'reffno'  => ':0BKP21851AF3EC2E0D4F56997EA19DFA',
    'charge'  => ':170377',
    'balace'  => ':1935',
]
```