# How to get value from string seprated by semicolons

Tags: php

I get data when any user request to serach url in browser  and i got her ip using that ip i convert that into string using API Like this.

```
$ip=1;US;USA;United States
```

here i need only iso3 code of that country how seprate that variable to get output like this.

```
$iso3=USA;
```

Comment: There should be a string split function. I think in PHP it's called explode

Comment: You may find a cool solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133780/explode-a-string-to-associative-array-without-using-loops

Answer (score 0):

```
$ipArr = explode(';',$ip);

if (is_array($ipArr)) {
    $iso3=$ipArr[2];
}
else {
    $iso3='same default value or error msg';
}
```

Comment: Your if statement is obsolete, you can simplify it as: `$iso3= $ipArr[2] ?? "default value or error msg"` see: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to use `explode` with the ';' as the delimiter. This is going to cut up the string at each ';' that it contains.

Example:

```
$ip = "1;US;USA;United States";

$ipValues = explode(';', $ip);
```

The result is going to be:

```
  [
      0 => '1',
      1 => 'US',
      2 => 'USA',
      3 => 'United States',
  ]
```

Then you simply assign the ISO code to your variable like so:

```
$iso3 = $ipValues[2];
```